# Problems with substitution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm having trouble getting path substitution working correctly. I have a bunch of source files in `SOURCES`:

```
@echo $(SOURCES)
foo.c bar.cpp bah.cxx
```

And I want a list of object files:

```
# Imaginary only because nothing works
@echo $(OBJECTS)
foo.o bar.o bah.o
```

I'm trying to build the list of `OBJECTS` with `patsubst`. First, this produces a list of source files and object files. Besides being wrong, it causes a duplicate of `_main` which fails a link.

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, ${SOURCES}) $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, ${SOURCES}) \
          $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, ${SOURCES}) $(patsubst %.cxx, %.o, ${SOURCES})
```

Second, this performs no substitutions. Not only is it wrong, I get back the original list in `SOURCES`.

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c %.cc %.cpp %.cxx, %.o, ${SOURCES})
```

Third, this produces the original list of source files:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.*, %.o, ${SOURCES})
```

I also tried using the following, which seems to multiply the files like rabbits:

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o) $(SOURCES:.cc=.o) \
          $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(SOURCES:.cxx=.o)
```

How does one perform a simple substitution of extensions when using a portable make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom's answer is correct.  Etan's will work too.  A shorter solution would be:

```
$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))
```

Comment: Much nicer than my solution. Though I probably would have used a foreach if I were actually writing mine for use to shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a filter-like function you can use that. Otherwise you can do it in stages:

```
SOURCES := foo.c bar.cpp bah.cxx

O := $(SOURCES)
$(info $(O))
O := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(O))
$(info $(O))
O := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(O))
$(info $(O))
O := $(patsubst %.cxx,%.o,$(O))
$(info $(O))
```

The problem with your first (and third since that is effectively identical) attempt is that patsubst leaves untouched any words in the input that do not match the pattern. So when you built OBJECTS up from multiple calls to patsubst you were duplicating (in each piece) all the SOURCSE entries that didn't match that pattern.

The problem with the second is that patsubst doesn't take multiple patterns so nothing matches that erroneous pattern and so you get SOURCES back entirely unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think patsubst is portable.  It is a GNU make feature.

I think one answer to your question is nested subsitutions, like:

```
$(patsubst %c,%.o,$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(patsubst .....)))
```